# New Kernel does not start in CentOS

Tags: centos, kernel

I upgraded my centOS kernel to  2.6.32-504.1.3.el6 using yum install command but when i reboot and open the kernel it does not run the new kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you didn't auto boot into the new kernel but rather the existing one then you need to check the grub config file. I suspect your default kernel is not the newest one.

`vi /boot/grub/grub.conf`

Towards the top of the file look for the line `default=x` where 'x' is a number usually 0 or 1

Look down the list of installed kernels your newest one should be at the top - that is number 0. change your `default=` to 0 and reboot. You should load the new kernel. If you have a console then you should be able to pick a kernel at boot time from the list.

Below is my grub.conf file as an example.

```
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (3.17.3-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-3.17.3-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_server/lv_swap LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=la
tarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=uk rd_LVM_LV=vg_server/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet audit=0
        initrd /initramfs-3.17.3-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.img
title CentOS (3.17.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-3.17.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_server/lv_swap LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=la
tarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=uk rd_LVM_LV=vg_server/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet audit=0
        initrd /initramfs-3.17.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64.img
title CentOS (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_server-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS rd_LVM_LV=vg_server/lv_swap LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcy
rheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=uk rd_LVM_LV=vg_server/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet audit=0
        initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64.img
```

The first kernel is 0, next is 1, 2 etc.